# Select all input tag in without certain attribute in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How to select all input tag in without certain attribute and checks each input value not empty in Jquery

Html

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" value="" id="UserName" class="form-error"  >
<input type="text" maxlength="255" value="" id="Password" class="form-error">
<input type="text" maxlength="255" value="" id="Group" class="form-error" inputname="test" >
<input type="text" maxlength="255" value="" id="Aka" class="form-error" inputname="money" >
```

I want to select all inputs from the current page which dont have attribute as 'inputname'.

Something like

In javascript

```
var inputs = $('input:not(:has(>[inputname]))');

jQuery.each(inputs, function(input) {
      if (input.value == '')  {
   $(input).next().removeClass('displayNone');
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get all divs which do not have class attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want

```
var inputs = $('input:not([inputname])');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/arewag)

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple selector in not $('input:not([inputname] [type="hidden"])');

Comment: @Jusnit: [`:not` takes only a "simple selector"](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation). So you string them together, e.g. `$('input:not([inputname]):not([type="hidden"])')`.

Answer (score 1):

$('input:not([inputname])') should do the trick?

Comment: When you see you've posted a duplicate answer, it's best to remove it.

Answer (score -4):

Use this
    var input = $(":input");

Comment: I want all inputs , but dont contain attribute inputname