# javascript replace div tags for p tags where it has no class

Tags: javascript, replace

I would like to replace div tags for p tags but only when the div tag does not have a class.

So this:

```
<div class="myDiv">
   <div>sdfglkhj sdfgkhl sdfkhgl sdf</div>
   <div>dsf osdfghjksdfg hsdfg</div>
</div>
```

Would become:

```
<div class="myDiv">
   <p>sdfglkhj sdfgkhl sdfkhgl sdf</p>
   <p>dsf osdfghjksdfg hsdfg</p>
</div>
```

I've tried `.replace("<div>", "<p>").replace("</div>","</p>")` but this replaces the closing tag of the one with a class.

Comment: Instaed of repalcing the tags why don't you add a class and specify the rules you want in css?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584098/how-to-change-an-element-type-using-jquery

Comment: well, you need to check the if the class is present first. You got jQuery or only pure javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be done with jQuery using the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector and [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('div:not([class])').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbj/ujLHk/

Comment: has you tried if it works in a something like this: <div class="">works?</div>

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('div').each(function () {
    var html = this.innerHTML;
    if (! $(this).attr('class')) {
       $(this).replaceWith('<p>' + html + '</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This does not work. `TypeError: $(this).replace is not a function`

Comment: sorry, i missed that, is replaceWith, now is edited...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you use a jQuery selector to get divs without a class:

[jQuery get all divs which do not have class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.myDiv div').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p/>');
});
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.myDiv div').each(function()
    {
        $(this).replaceWith($('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>'))
    });
});
```