# Get specific elements that have no CSS class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a page with multiple h2 tags. I want to get all the h2 tags that **do not** have a css class.

So in this example:

```
<h2>Headline 1</h2>
<p>content 1</p>

<h2 class="some-class">Headline 2</h2>
<p>content 2</p>

<h2>Headline 3</h2>
<p>content 3</p>

<h2 class="another-class">Headline 4</h2>
<p>content 4</p>
```

I want to get the h2 elements wrapping "Headline 1" and "Headline 3" in the above example.

Doing this:

```
var h2_tags = $("h2");
```

Will result in getting all H2's, which I don't want. How can I get only the ones without any CSS class?

Comment: That's an HTML class, not a CSS class. CSS has class selectors, it doesn't have classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses. @Quentin - My bad on the terminology, however, I believe everyone will clearly understand what I was referring to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[class]` is a valid selector, so you can just do this:

```
$('h2:not([class])')
```

Comment: Worked great, nice and clean too. Will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('h2:not([class])')
```

should work