# How to find elements without a class in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<div class="one">One<div>
<div class="two">two<div>
<div >three<div>
<div >four<div>
<div class="three">five<div>
```

How would I find the div elements which don't have a class attribute? ie three and four?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get all divs which do not have class attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:not` selector to filter

```
$('div:not([class])');
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `:not` selector

```
$('div:not([class])');
```

here is [**API**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

And a [simple Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/eRe5Y/2/)

Comment: API also says it is better to use .not() than :not

Comment: @Benubird  Yeah that is why I attached Api for full fledged Idea :)

Comment: @Benubird It says it's clearer, which is arguable if that's the case in this example. As one selector, it can be sent to `qSA()` *as is*.

Comment: @alex Yes.Agreed for that.

Answer (score 3):

Combine the `:not()` selector with the attribute present selector `[class]`.

```
$("div:not([class])")
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RcdV/).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) with [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
$('div').not('[class]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not wanting to select all the dividers which have no classes, you can use `nth-child` to select specific ones if you know exactly where they are within a container. This will select your class-less dividers:

```
$('div:nth-child(3)') // Selects the third divider
$('div:nth-child(4)') // Selects the fourth divider
$('div:nth-child(3), div:nth-child(4)') // Selects both
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/BUnEf/).

Alternatively you can select using `.prev()` and `.next()`:

```
$('div.two').next() // Selects the divider after div class="two"
$('div.three').prev() // Selects the divider before div class="three"
```

Comment: But how do you find elements without a class if you _don't_ already know which ones they are?

Comment: It really depends what you're looking for, @nnnnnn. You could use `:contains` if you're looking for specific text, for example.

Comment: My point is that the OP is very clear on what to look for, i.e., divs that don't specify a class. Your answer doesn't cover that...

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it. You could use .children() to get the list and then index into that. Or you could look up the second element and use .next() to get its sibling.

Comment: But how do you find elements without a class if you _don't_ already know which ones they are?