# Jquery doesn't have a selector for "no class"

Tags: jquery, selector

I have some a table and I need to keep only few contents in this table, so I have this

```
 $(truc).find('tr').each(function(lig) {
        if (lig != 0 && (!$(this).children(':first').not('')) && (!$(this).children(':first').hasClass('main-title')) && (!$(this).children(':first').hasClass('top-top-title'))) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
        ;
    }
```

I need help for the `(!$(this).children(':first').not(''))` because I need to select the line where the first child has no class(not even an empty class) and I don't know which instructions I need

**Edit :** I resolved myself witch a check on `$(this).children(':first')` if they have an attribute class
`$(this).children(':first').attr('class')`, so if an element has no class, it doesn't enter in the if

Comment: this is my var with the table inside

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute

Comment: Dirty flow has already given the answer to your question..

Comment: You can get class attribute and compare it to ''. Just iterate through children.

Comment: I already saw this question, but I don't know how to use the answers, or they don't work, I tried $(this).children(':first').not('class');   $(this).children(':first').not('[class]');  $(this).children(':first').not([class]),  same results

Comment: @Valinor what are the cases you want to check?

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but I found a similar solution : I check on my $(this).children(':first') if they have an attribute class <<<<
 $(this).children(':first').attr('class') >>>>> , so if an element has no class, it doesn't enter in the if.

Comment: @Valinor add your solution as answer, it could be useful for other users

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
!$(this).children(':first').get(0).className
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, I have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the attribute, like this

```
(!$(this).children(':first').not('[class]'))
```