# Select element without style in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Selecting elements by classnames is easy. But, is it possible to select any DOM-element who has no class set at all in jQuery? Kind of empty-style-selector.

Example:

```
<div class="nope">
     <div>You need me!</div>
</div>
<span class="foo">Not me</span>

var answer = $("selector-im-looking-for").text(); // You need me!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('div').not('[class]');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wwjr9/), note that this approach fails to select the `<span>` element ( pertinent HTML below).

Or, to select all elements without a class attribute:

```
$('body *:not("[class]")')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wwjr9/1/), note that this *also* fails to select the `<span>` element.

The universal selector (`*`) is implied in the case of a pseudo-class selector being used without a tag-name, but in the event it's used I prefer to be explicit about it, though it is optional in this context.

Further, to select *all* elements, within the `<body>`, with either no `class` attribute, *or* with a class attribute, but no set class-name:

```
$('body *').filter(function(){
    return !this.className || !this.className.length;
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wwjr9/2/), this approach, because it tests for both the absence of a `className` property as well as an empty/zero-length `className` property, successfully finds the `<span>`.

The above demos were all used with the following HTML:

```
<div class="nope">
    Some text that should not be selected.
     <div>You need me!</div>
</div>
<span class="foo">Not me</span>
<span class="">Me too (probably)</span>
```

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: Tnx! This is the selector Im looking for. I will accept it as answer in about 9 minutes...

Answer (score 3):

Are you expecting the following?

```
var answer = $("div").text(); // You need me!
```

Or

```
var answer = $(":not(.nope)").text(); // You need me!
```

Edit following clarification:

Like this?

```
var answer = $('div:not([class])');
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer. But Im looking for an selector that selects any elements with no class set.

Comment: Tnx, the last one was right but I can only accept one. But, tnx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$('div:not([class])')
```

REFERENCE

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

[jQuery get all divs which do not have class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute)

Comment: Tnx for your correct answer but I accepted David Thomas' one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter,

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('class') === null;
}).each(function(){
    //iterate item
})
```

Comment: I hope I've caused you no offense, but I chose to format your answer (in order to present the code *as code*, and for readability). For formatting help (to help you format code as code) please have a look at the [Markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/). :)