# How to select elements that have no classes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I need to select all `<input type="submit">` elements, that have no class specifier.

With:

```
<input class="Submit" type="submit" value="Save" name="action_1">
<input class="Button" type="submit" value="Save as" name="action_2">
<input                type="submit" value="Save and Continue" name="action_3">
<input class="Cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" name="action_4">
```

It should select the 3rd one only.

I can imagine this CSS:

```
input[type="submit"]:not(ANY CLASS){
}
```

**But, what should I write as "ANY CLASS"?** Or is there a different approach alltogehter? I could enumerate all known classes there, but this is tedious and might change over time.

Note:

- I am looking for a CSS-only solution. This makes [this answer not a
  duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute).
- I want to specify "no classes at all" not omitting one
  single class. This makes [this answer not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-class).

Comment: Can't you simply apply changes to other classes and leave the default `.input` selector suited for the input that has no class ?

Comment: @Brewal Unfortunately not, as I am creating a "super-css" that gets applied on top of an existing page. My CSS should be suitable for use with the "stylish"-plugin for Firefox.

Comment: I voted for reopening, as the linked answers do not actually answer this question. Although they are not wrong, they only provide a workaround, not an answer.

Comment: As the one who answered the second duplicate question I can confirm that it's completely different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `:not([class])`, which means select an `input` element that does not have a `class` attribute.

```css
input[type="submit"]:not([class]){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="Submit" type="submit" value="Save" name="action_1">
<input class="Button" type="submit" value="Save as" name="action_2">
<input                type="submit" value="Save and Continue" name="action_3">
<input class="Cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" name="action_4">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a selector like this:

```
input:not([class]) {
    /* style for inputs without classes */
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fd5dq03a/)**

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962250/643482)

Comment: Thanks, especially for the JSFiddle demo. Nice!

Comment: Glad to help. If the classes on your site are dynamic (added/removed from elements via javascript), you may want to also consider catching for this alternative `input[class=""] { ... }` which would catch elements with blank classes -- [**updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fd5dq03a/1/)