# how to add class to all tables without class in JS or JQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to add class in JS or JQ to all the tables without class in a site, some already as class so i need it to add the class only to the tables who doesn't have... please advice? 
edit: i also need the class to be unique with number after the name of the class

```
$('table').each(function(i){
                $(this).addClass('classname',i);
            });
```

Comment: `addClass()` won't do anything if the class you want to add is already exposed by the element -- there is no need to handle that case yourself.

Comment: Do you just want all your tables to get this new class, or do you specifically need to select only tables without any classes?

Comment: There's no clear problem in the question unless you were trying to add `i` as a class but only to those that do not have `classname`.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the same as this post describing how to find an element without classes (just for the table element instead of a div): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle: You changed the wording of this question without first asking the OP if that's what was intended.

Comment: the class i need to add needs to be numbered so it will be unique, that is why i tried to usr "i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add a class to only those tables without any classes (and not just all your tables), you can use:

```
$('table').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).attr('class') || !$(this).attr('class').length) $(this).addClass('zzz')
})
```

Comment: `attr('class')` will be undefined if no attribute exists .. will throw error trying to get length

Comment: @j08691 hello, this function almost done what i intended i also needs it to do unique number to the class, this is what i tried: `$('table').each(function(i) {
          if (!$(this).attr('class') || !$(this).attr('class').length) $(this).addClass('oldtableclassname',i)
           }); `

Answer (score 1):

the addClass method only adds a class if it not exist in the selected element.

this works

```
$('table').addClass('classname');
```

Comment: the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check with not selector if particular class is not applied then apply it:

```
$("table:not(.classname)").addClass("classname");
```

### Update:

But as others have mentioned you don't need to do that as addClass will take care of not adding class if it is there.

Comment: Sure, but why would you?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to target tables that don't have any class, you can use :not and the attribute selector

```
$('table:not([class!=""])').addClass('test');
```

that would be the same as:

```
$('table[class=""],table:not([class])').addClass('test');
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Note that the question has been edited and at the time of this answer it required targeting tables without classes (in plural)

Comment: hello, this function almost done what i intended i also needs it to do unique number to the class, this is what i tried: `$('table[class=""],table:not([class])').each(function(i) {
                $(this).addClass('nameofclass',i);
            });` please advice ?

Comment: You almost got it. Try with addClass('nameofclass'+i), so you will get nameofclass0,nameofclass1, etc.