# Styling Bootstrap-tables after AJAX

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a site built in WordPress/WooCommerce. I didn't ask this question on the WordPress-StackExchange since the question isn't about the WordPress-/WooCommerce-part.

On the site, there are a few `<table>`'s, that needed styling. So I added this jQuery-snippet, to add the `.table`-class to all the tables ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897778/how-to-add-class-to-all-tables-without-class-in-js-or-jq)).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  // Make all tables into Bootstrap-tables
  jQuery( 'main' ).find( 'table' ).each( function() {
      jQuery( this ).addClass( 'table' );
    }
  );
});
```

However... On one of the pages (the cart), there is an AJAX-request that updates the cart. And when it returns the new information, then the table no longer has the class (or the stylings).

I would hate to style that table manually, when everthing is 'right there', delivered from Bootstrap.

I considered these two options:

- A) Add something to my script, that checks for AJAX-request or something like that? And if so, - how do I do that?

or

- B) Do something, so the Bootstrap-styles applied to all `<table>`-elements (and not just `<table class='table'>`-elements? And if so, - how do I do that? Changing bootstrap.min.css seem like a bad idea.

They both seem hacky/clumbsy. Am I missing a better way of doing this?

Comment: `"main"` is class or tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ajaxComplete`

this work when every ajax request completes.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
      $("table").addClass("table");
});
```