# jQuery selector element with no class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have let's say three divs

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div></div>
     .
     .
<div class="n"></div>
```

Is there a way to select the div that doesnt have any class? 
I dont know the order of the elements in DOM, so using something like `.next()` wouldnt work.

Comment: Uhm, use "div"? Or third child?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get all divs which do not have class attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute)

Comment: @AllDani then you would get all divs

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour, maybe two at the most, and it pays you that time back right away.

Comment: Next time, please be sure to include important details like the edit about order in the *first* version of the question.

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with the :not() pseudo-class selector:

```
$('div:not([class])')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: don't think the downvotes are fair when the question changes.

```
 $('div:not([class])')
```

Comment: Why downvote this? It's correct. A bit sparse, but... [Okay: It's no longer correct with the edited question...]

Comment: @AllDani: I saw it, but the downvote I was commenting on was from before the edit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder got you

Comment: too many downvoters downvoting for no reason on this site.  it's becoming a farce

Comment: @Pete if I believed it made a difference, I'd complain too.

Comment: I upvoted to redress the balance - but next time, please add a description/ reason, not just some code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div:not(.a, .b, .n)').addClass('red')
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">123</div>
<div class="b">123</div>
<div>123</div>

<div class="n">123</div>
```

You can use `:not()` to exclude div

Answer (score 0):

You can either by css or by jquery separate the div have no class. Example shown below. Both can filter the element without class attribute. In css it select div without class using not selector. And in Jquery also method is same as like css.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   div:not([class]){ color: red; }
  </style>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var noClassElement = $('div:not([class])');
    console.log(noClassElement)
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="a">sdf df sfsdf</div>
  <div class="b">sdfsdsdsdf</div>
  <div>dfgdfg</div>
  <div class="n">sdfsdf</div>
 </body>
</html>
```